# Bike restarts it's electronic equipments!

Tags: motorcycle, battery, apache-rtr

Looks like I have many issues with my motorcycle. Yesterday night my motorcycle stopped twice while I was on my way to home. On my display everything turns off and turned on by itself. And the battery indicator and the fuel capacity indicator will be blinking. Any attempt to restart will be failure.

The only way to turn it back on is to turn off manually with key and turn it on. In this case self start won't work sometimes and I have to use kick start. What might be the issue?

The battery is mostly a year old.
One advice which I got is to clean the battery nodes which might have some wax kind of stuff accumulated  on it. I have opened the side cover and didn't get what to clean there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very general question, so this is a very general answer.

What you describe can be caused by many things, but most common is a loose connection or broken wire.

I would suggest you check battery ground, and then all wiring for any damage like pinched or broken wires. Look for loose connections and corrosion.

Fix any issues you find.

Comment: Means, no need to clean the battery connection? like what I have heard?

Comment: When you are told “look for loose connections and corrosion” then the battery connection and ALL the connections in between need to be checked ...

Comment: Ok, will check it and will update after.

Comment: Yep, found a loose wire which was touching the other metal parts. Didn't got this problem after fixing it! Let's see what will happen next.

Comment: Glad you were able to find the issue.